# How to check which interface(s) a service is bound to?

Tags: networking, network-interface, services, netstat

`netstat` and similar commands provide information on services bound to an IP. This information is however limited when a service binds to "all available interfaces":

```
root@srv ~# netstat -tulpn | grep 22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1077/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1077/sshd
```

In the case above, the SSH daemon bound to all available interfaces, but it is not explicit about which ones.

How to check all interfaces (or IP addresses) a service bound to?

Answer (score 4):

Try `ss`.

Something like:

```
ss -o state established '( dport = :ssh or sport = :ssh )'
```

Might be what you are looking for:

```
$ ss -o state established '( dport = :ssh or sport = :ssh )'
Netid Recv-Q Send-Q        Local Address:Port                         Peer Address:Port                
tcp   0      0               10.12.11.93:ssh                            10.22.96.0:57244                 timer:(keepalive,119min,0)
```

Man page online: https://linux.die.net/man/8/ss

Comment: Thanks but this lists the established connections, not the binding (which may not have a connection right now)

Comment: @WoJ For the *binding* maybe this is the answer you seek: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16058/191550

Comment: Thanks again, but this is the routing - independent of which service bound to which interface.